# Rewriting Winform to Console App- trouble with global var

Tags: variables, console, global

It might be really trivial but I am having some trouble with some variables in C# console app(Rewriting from Winform app). Here is a bit of code so you can get the problem.

```
Public partial class Form1:Form
{
  private string ArchieveDir;
  private string IncomingDir;
  private string ProblemDir;
  private string DuplicateDir;
  private string Downloader App;

  public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection myCon = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(X.Settings.Settings.ConnectionString);
     XmlDocument cfg = new XmlDocument();

     try
     {
        cfg.Load("config.xml");

        ArchiveDir = cfg.SelectSingleNode("/ExcelRecalc/Archive").InnerText;
        IncomingDir = cfg.SelectSingleNode("/ExcelRecalc/Incoming").InnerText;
        ProblemDir = cfg.SelectSingleNode("/ExcelRecalc/Problem").InnerText;
        DuplicateDir = cfg.SelectSingleNode("/ExcelRecalc/Duplicate").InnerText;
        DownloaderApp = cfg.SelectSingleNode("/ExcelRecalc/DownloaderApp").InnerText;

     }
     catch( Exception ex)
     {
        System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     }
   }
   [STAThread]

   static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());

    }

    private bool Calculate(DataRow dr)
    {
     //Application quite long, used in method DownloadIntoDir//
    }

    private void DownloadIntoDir()
    {
     //Require no user input, get files from specified directory, uses Calculte to     perform calculation, saves into DB using a conn//
    }

    private void ConnectRecords()
    {
     //Requires no user input, connects file (produced by DownloadIntoDir) to another table in DB//
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GSI.Settings.Settings.ConnectionString);
        DownloadIntoDir();
        ConnectRecords();
        Application.Exit();
    }
 }
 }
```

Okay that is pretty much the whole program. Methods Calculate, DownloadIntoDir and ConnectRecords are all working fine. However, in Winform, I have saved DB connection and  variables, which store directory info into app form, which then could be accessed by all methods. (Both ,directory and connection, are required for all methods). It functions perferctly fine ( and without user input) in Winform. However I have trouble with storing variables and connection in such a way that it is available to all methods. What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend defining a class that contains properties for all of the variables you need to access throughout your program, then have a single instance of that class as a `private readonly` variable, and initialize it in your constructor.

The one thing to make sure of is that you're keeping everything safe if you're using threads.  If you are using threads, I recommend checking out [this page](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).